# Will iPhone App Update to new version will remove all the ratings?

Tags: iphone

I plan to update my app with new features. If I publish a new version say V 1.0.1 then will I loose all my ratings from version 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple splits your App's ratings into two sections; **"Current Version"** and **"All Versions"**.

The preference on the App Store is to display the "current version" ratings, however aggregated historical ratings and reviews are also available.

[image: App Store]

Comment: awesome! thanks for the answer. I will go ahead and update the app with new features. Thanks!